# rails simple_form fields not related to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have an existing form which is tied to a model named 'Order', but i want to add new form fields that will capture Credit Card info such as name, cc number, etc to be processed on a 3rd party payment gateway.

But since i don't want to save CC info in our database, there are no corresponding columns of that in my order table. And this gives me an error when submitting the form that those Credit card input fields are not 'part' of the order model.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple\_form without for (non model form)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181143/simple-form-without-for-non-model-form)

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the above linked question. That one is about entire forms not connected to models. This one is about having selected fields not connected to the form's model.

Comment: This would give you all sorts of issues with PCI compliance and is extremely dangerous!! Although you're not saving the CC information to your database, if you're submitting it to your server all of the details will be in your logs, if anyone has access to your logs they have access to unencrypted client CC information. You should avoid submitting this data to your server at all. If you _really_ need to, look into client side encryption (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/client/credit-cards). Otherwise use direct post forms or third party drop in tools. Good luck!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use attr_accessor

```
 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessor :card_number


 end
```

Now you can do `Order.first.card_number = '54421542122'` or use it in your form or whatever else you need to do.

See here for ruby docs http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor
and here for a useful stackoverflow question [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)

Don't get it mixed up with attr_accessible!  [Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

Comment: I have a follow-up question, after i submit the form, on the controller, how can i "unset" those CC related fields upon call to 'model.save' because it might throw errors?

Comment: you could use `params.except(:card_number)` in your controller.

Answer (score 48):

If I understand your answer correctly, what you want to do is explained in the official wiki page here: [Create a fake input that does NOT read attributes](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-a-fake-input-that-does-NOT-read-attributes). You can use a field not related to any real database column by Edward's suggestion, however you don't need to define an attribute in your model if the form field is nothing to do with the model.

In summary, the trick explained in the page is defining a custom input called 'FakeInput' and use it like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :agreement, as: :fake %>
  ....
```

Do not forget to restart your rails server after adding/modifying a custom input as Fitter Man commented.

**UPDATE:** Please note that [the official wiki page has updated](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-a-fake-input-that-does-NOT-read-attributes/_history) and the sample code on the wiki page is not working for those which use older versions of SimpleForm. Use code below instead if you encounter an error like `undefined method merge_wrapper_options for...`. I'm using 3.0.1 and this code works well.

```
class FakeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  # This method only create a basic input without reading any value from object
  def input
    template.text_field_tag(attribute_name, input_options.delete(:value), input_html_options)
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice. I had never noticed that.

Comment: You may have to restart/reload your web server to have this picked up.

Comment: For some reason it does not work anymore. `undefined method merge_wrapper_options for #<FakeInput:0x007fbe5e32beb8>`

Comment: @Trein What version of Rails/SimpleForm are you using?

Comment: @baxang I'm using v3.0.2. Does it work on rc versions? I unfortunately cannot use rc version on this project (policies...).

Comment: @Trein I use SimpleForm v3.0.1 with Rails 4.0.x and don't have the same issue.

Comment: same problem for me... rails 4.0.3 and I tried simple_form 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2.

Comment: @Trein @jon-kern  That wiki post applies to `simple_form` version >= 3.1.0.rc1 only. I posted an explanation at [this related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303091/undefined-method-merge-wrapper-options/26331237)

Comment: I think the wiki page I linked has updated to reflect recent changes in SimpleForm. I updated my answer that now includes the previous code snippet. @admgc

Comment: What about I want to add **fake_boolean**? official docu only has **fake_select_input**. Hopefully there are a list of all fake properties.

Answer (score 45):

The best way to handle this is to use `simple_fields_for` like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>

  <%= simple_fields_for :other do |o| %>
    <%= o.input :change_password, as: :boolean, label: 'I want to change my password' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In this example, I have added a new field called `change_password` which is not part of the underlying `user` model.

The reason this is a good approach, is that it lets you use any of the simple form inputs / wrappers as fields.  I don't care for the answer by @baxang, because it doesn't allow you to use different types of inputs.  This seems more flexible.

Notice though for this to work, I had to pass `:other` to `simple_fields_for`.  You can pass any string/symbol **as long as there is not a model with that same name**.

I.e. unfortunately I can't pass `:user`, as simple_form would try to instantiate a User model, and we'd get the same error message again...

Comment: The simplest answers are the best. Works for me.

Answer (score 14):

Also if you're just trying to add something and get it into the `params`, but leaving it out of the model's hash, you could just do FormTagHelpers.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Example:

```
    <%= simple_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>   invitation_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
       <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
       <%= f.input field %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :object_name, @object.class.name %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag :object_id, @object.id %>
    <% end -%>
```

Answer (score 8):

I found a very simple (and somewhat strange) workaround.

Just add the `input_html` option with any `value` key inside. E.g:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.input :whatever, input_html: {value: ''}
```

Tested simple_from versions: 3.2.1, 3.5.1

Comment: worked right away, awesome, thanks!