# Cannot find FakeInput

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, input, simple-form

I am trying add a fake input to simple_form using the following suggestion ([rails simple_form fields not related to the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146466/rails-simple-form-fields-not-related-to-the-model/14659270#14659270)), but it does not work for me.

This is my HAML code for adding a fake input field.

```
= f.input :agrees_to_terms, :as => :fake
```

I put the following class in app/inputs/fake_input.rb

```
class FakeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  # This method only create a basic input without reading any value from object
  def input
    template.text_field_tag(attribute_name, nil, input_html_options)
  end
end
```

I get the following runtime error

```
No input found for fake
```

I have two initializers that were generated by Rails Composer: simple_form.rb and simple_form_bootstrap.rb

How can I make Rails find my FakeInput class?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and a server restart resolved it.