# No input found error with Simple Form after editing and saving files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, simple-form-for

I'm trying to implement a custom Fake Input ([found in this article](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-a-fake-input-that-does-NOT-read-attributes)) with a Simple Form For. This is my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for :results, { url: admin_add_sites_path } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :no_merchandisers, as: :fake %>
  <%= f.input :site_codes_to_add, as: :fake %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

When I first implemented the input I received an error:

```
No input found for fake
```

The answer in this [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170785/cannot-find-fakeinput) tells me to restart my server. This temporarily fixes the above issue for me.

But, whenever I edit and save a file (it was happening when editing a controller file), the error pops up again and I have to restart my server to be able to continue. Has anyone else experienced this before? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I haven't heard about "fake" inputs, but try adding `value: nil` to your inputs. That might work.

Comment: Sorry to clarify; from the Fake input article: 

"Sometimes I just need a custom input for extra params But all the existing inputs read from object's attributes". I use it because `:no_merchandisers`, and `:site_codes_to_add` are not columns in a model. But I still want to capture their data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to this problem that I use regularly (though I don't use Simple Form). First is to use `value: nil`. All this does is overrides the default `value` method that would normally look for the model attribute. It still submits with the rest of the form.

```
<%= f.input :no_merchandisers, value: nil %>
```

The second solution is to use a "tag" input, depending on what your input actually is:

```
<%= text_field_tag "results[no_merchandisers]", value_variable %>
```

or maybe:

```
<%= check_box_tag "results[no_merchandisers]", value_variable, checked_variable %>
```

Now, neither of these solutions fixes the `as: :fake` problem, just replaces it entirely. I'm not familiar with Simple Form, so I don't know how that additional code would (or wouldn't) work.

Comment: I think using the tag option and then styling the form without using Simple Form may be the way to go. Simple Form is just a wrapper around `form_for` which expects to take in an model. If I wanted to have a form without needing a model then the "tag" input would be the solution I guess. Thanks for taking the time to answer that Ryan.