# simple_form sending parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to send an extra parameter submiting a form in rails using simple_form
I thought this would do the trick:

`<%= simple_form_for(@user, :groupId => 1) do |f| %>`

but in tne controller, the parameter is ignored

I found an answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828416/simple-form-send-a-extra-parameter) but I really like to have a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: user_path(@user, :groupId => 1) do |f| %>
```

`simple_form_for` has a similar usage to `form_for`. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for